# Inserting record in database using parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to use parameters when saving a record into `tblholidays`

```vb
Dim rs As New OdbcCommand("", con)
With rs
    .CommandText = "Insert into tblholidays (Holiday,Date,Comment) values (@Holiday,@date,@Comment)"
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Holiday", txtholiday.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dtpicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", txtcomment.Text)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

I'm getting the error

> Column 'Holiday' cannot be null.

I'm still trying to learn how to use parameters, can someone help?

Comment: What is the command text? You are creating a command and executing it without specifying the command to execute. Please add this info to your question

Comment: Use [MySQL connector methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) instead.

Comment: I didn't notice that the command text is not there. I added the command text now.

Comment: Not sure what is the cause of the stated error message. However noticed that Date and Comment are reserved words for MySql. You should get a syntax error if you don't put them inside backticks  (you can type a backtick pressing ALT+096)

Comment: I doubt that you can use "@" as a parameter prefix for MySQL using an ODBC driver.  That prefix is actually a Microsoft convention, with the MySQL equivalent being ":".  Connector/Net, i.e. the dedicated MySQL provider, supports "@" for compatibility with `SqlClient` but I'm not sure that MySQL ODBC drivers or OLE DB providers have the same support.

Comment: I tried to use parameters because of the error i got when i save a string that has a single quote. and also i want to get used to using parameters as what others recommend.

Comment: Use the proper namespaces for IO with `MySql` as @Alexander mentioned... `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`... IMHO don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` and specify the database type. The problem is it has to infer the database type for your query parameter and sometimes it gets it wrong, don't rely on this function; stop using it now.

Comment: and always pass and store dates as dates, not strings